# Good Computational (Applied) Probability Book With Good Problems

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I come from a math major background. I took an honors probability course in my year 2 which was very theory heavy (Covers probability rigorously from a measure theory point of view) and very application light. Needless to say, I feel like my problem skills after that course are little to non.

I am looking for a good probability book which covers a lot of **computational problems and applied problems**. I don't care how well the theory is written in the book since I feel I am very confident when it comes to theory (at least at the undergraduate/early post graduate level), but I hope its very practical and the problems in it cover a wide variety of application / computational techniques.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these the things you had in mind? https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Problems-Solutions-Stefan-Hollos-ebook/dp/B00CK5QJFS, https://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Probability-Statistics-4th/dp/007179557X, https://www.gwern.net/docs/statistics/1973-meshalkin-collectionofproblemsinprobabilitytheory.pdf, https://www.amazon.com/Challenging-Problems-Probability-Solutions-Mathematics/dp/0486653552, http://personal.vu.nl/h.c.tijms/ExamQuestionsUP.pdf, https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/6300/suppl_file/6300-solutionsmanual_free.pdf, http://athenasc.com/prob-solved_2ndedition.pdf

Comment: @Moo Thanks, exactly what I needed!